# React Native tutorial: npm install froze

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

But when I run the command `npm install -g expo-cli`, it freezes here:

> [            ......] \ extract:@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux: sill extract @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.9.9 extracted to C:\Users\edkol\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging@expo\traveling-fastlane-linux-db114743 (362890ms)

How long is this command supposed to take? It looks like it's trying to download and install a whole Linux distro?! Should I keep waiting?

Comment: How long have you waiting for it to install? Some packages can take a long time to get ready. Issue related to your problem [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/398). You could try to clean npm cache, using `npm cache clean --force`.

Comment: I don't remember how long I've been waiting; it's got to be at least 15 minute though, in my estimation.

Comment: As [this](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/398#issuecomment-324799018) comment says, it can take a "little" bit to install. Not sure if 15 minutes is too much for it. I recommend you to clean the npm cache and try again.

Comment: Can you `--verbose` option with the install. It can help provide more details.

Comment: Tried cleaning the cache and it looks like it froze again. Let me add the verbose option and try again...

Comment: Hmm, now it freezes here: `[       ...........] - postinstall: verb lock using C:\Users\edkol\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-00ee901e47de75aa.lock for C:\Users\edkol\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging`

Comment: if you are using vscode , maybe you better try it in terminal not vscode ,https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28593#issuecomment-313238852

Comment: I was using the Windows command prompt.